# After submitting a comment, how can I get updates in my inbox?

Tags: support, comments, global-inbox

I would like to know, if it is possible to have an update in the Global Inbox (top left) for questions where I only placed a comment.

Sometimes, I ask a question in a comment to the questioning person. And I would obviously like to know if he commented back to me.

One workaround is putting it as a favourite, but is it also possible to have a notification in my inbox after placing a comment?

Thanks in advance,
I hope I'm asking the right question on the right stackExchange =)

Comment: You are asking in the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, if the person is replying to your comment they'll use [@Marnix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) in it, which will add the comment to your inbox. If they don't do that it's assumed the comment wasn't meant for you, and you don't get bothered about it (notifying everyone in a comment thread every time anyone posts a comment would probably get annoying)

Comment: Ah ok, so it depends on the user. I will do so in the future as well than. Thanks.